# Partition of set

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that the number of integer partitions of 2n into three parts, such
that the sum of any two parts is greater than the third, is equal to the
number of integer partitions of n with exactly three parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: For each partition $\langle p_1,p_2,p_3\rangle$ of $n$ consider the partition $\langle p_1+p_2,p_1+p_3,p_2+p_3\rangle$ of $2n$. Can you recover $\langle p_1,p_2,p_3\rangle$ from $\langle p_1+p_2,p_1+p_3,p_2+p_3\rangle$? Can every partition of $2n$ of the desired type be constructed in this way?